# Web scraping of multiple web pages with python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am webscraping indeed.nl for "Junior UX Designer" in "Nederland". The website for that search term contains 6 webpages with vacancies - meaning, if one webpage contains 15 vacancies, I should get in total around 90 vacancies.
However, when I put it into a json file, I can see that I receive 90 rows - however, multiple duplicates are in there, and many job vacancies are not even displayed in the file.

This is the code I'm using:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

jobs_NL = []
for i in range(1,7):
  url = "https://nl.indeed.com/vacatures?q=junior+ux+designer&l=Nederland&start="+str(i)
  
  print("Getting page",i)
  
  page = requests.get(url)

  html = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

  job_title = html.find_all("table", class_="jobCard_mainContent")

  for item in job_title:
      title = item.find("h2").get_text() 
      company = item.find("span", class_="companyName").get_text()
      location = item.find("div", class_="companyLocation").get_text()

      if item.find("div", class_="salary-snippet") != None:
        salary = item.find("div", class_="heading6 tapItem-gutter metadataContainer").get_text()
      else:
        salary = "No salary found"

      vacancy = {
          "title": title,
          "company": company,
          "location": location,
          "salary": salary
          }
      jobs_NL.append(vacancy)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to multiply the `start` variable by `10` to get correct page:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

jobs_NL = []
for i in range(7):
    url = "https://nl.indeed.com/vacatures?q=junior+ux+designer&l=Nederland&start={}".format(
        10 * i
    )

    print("Getting page", i)

    page = requests.get(url)
    html = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    job_title = html.find_all("table", class_="jobCard_mainContent")

    for item in job_title:
        title = item.find("h2").get_text()
        company = item.find("span", class_="companyName").get_text()
        location = item.find("div", class_="companyLocation").get_text()

        if item.find("div", class_="salary-snippet") != None:
            salary = item.find(
                "div", class_="heading6 tapItem-gutter metadataContainer"
            ).get_text()
        else:
            salary = "No salary found"

        vacancy = {
            "title": title,
            "company": company,
            "location": location,
            "salary": salary,
        }
        jobs_NL.append(vacancy)

df = pd.DataFrame(jobs_NL)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
...
90                                           UX Designer | SaaS Platform                                       StarApple                                     Amersfoort  €3.000 - €4.500 per maand
91                                                    Frontend Developer                                      JustBetter                                        Alkmaar            No salary found
92                                                     Software Engineer                              Infinitas Learning                                    Thuiswerken            No salary found
93                                                         UX Researcher                  Cognizant Technology Solutions                                      Amsterdam            No salary found
94                                            Junior Front End developer                                       StarApple                                 Zeist+1 plaats  €2.500 - €3.000 per maand
95                                  nieuwSenior User Experience Designer                                         Trimble                                     Bodegraven            No salary found
96                                  Senior UX Designer - Research Agency                        Found Professionals B.V.                             Amsterdam+1 plaats            No salary found
97                                                HubSpot marketing lead                                          Comaxx                                         Waalre            No salary found
98                                  nieuwJunior Technisch CRO Specialist                                   Finest People                                 Amsterdam West           €50.000 per jaar
99                                                         iOS developer                                       Infoplaza                                         Houten            No salary found
```